# Проброс портов в контейнере docker?

Tags: docker

На роутере проброшен порт 62000->62000.

Контейнер запущен

```
docker run -it --restart=always -p 192.168.0.103:62000:80 debian9
```

Docker port показывает

```
80/tcp -> 192.168.0.103:62000
```

При обращении извне `http://example.com:62000` сайт, лежащий в контейнере, не работает.

После

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

работает.

Как заставить сайт отображаться при автостарте докера?

Логи docker

```
root@server:/home/user/docker/debian9# docker run -itd --restart=always -p 61550:80 debian9 /bin/bash
124bed0a38985f752210f26d4ccdcebac27e367f8fc0795963cca0981162536b
root@server:/home/user/docker/debian9# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
124bed0a3898        debian9             "/bin/bash"         11 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:61550->80/tcp   sharp_wozniak
root@server:/home/user/docker/debian9# docker logs 124
root@server:/home/user/docker/debian9#
```

Логи apache2

```
[Tue Oct 31 13:03:10.370277 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 168] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 31 13:03:10.370677 2017] [core:notice] [pid 168] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Еще раз

```
[Tue Oct 31 13:03:10.370277 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 168] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 31 13:03:10.370677 2017] [core:notice] [pid 168] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 31 14:00:57.377119 2017] [core:warn] [pid 37] AH00098: pid file /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Oct 31 14:00:57.384675 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 37] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 31 14:00:57.384767 2017] [core:notice] [pid 37] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 31 14:09:33.411042 2017] [core:warn] [pid 36] AH00098: pid file /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Oct 31 14:09:33.431123 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 36] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 31 14:09:33.431219 2017] [core:notice] [pid 36] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: начните с просмотра логов контейнера — по какой причине apache не может/хочет слушать 80-й порт.

Comment: *docker: command not found* — перевод: не найдена программа/команда `docker`. зачем вы пытаетесь запустить программу docker внутри контейнера? вы же её вряд ли там устанавливали. а форматированный текст лучше прилагать к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) — комментарии для этого абсолютно неприспособлены.

Comment: Что, решения  не существует?

Comment: @Сергей приложите форматированный текст логов докера и apache к вопросу, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/738213/edit). В комментарий писать ничего не нужно

Comment: Собрал образ через Dockerfile, добавив в конце строчку CMD /etc/init.d/apache2 start, однако проблема осталась.

Comment: @Сергей вы точно приложили содержимое `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: Еще раз выложил.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Тема закрыта.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так:

```
docker run -it --restart=always -p 62000:80 debian9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker run -it --restart=always -p 127.0.0.1:62000:80 debian9
```

в iptables открыть порт для доступа извне и настроить прокси в apache2 или лучше в NGINX, чтобы адресация была на локальный хост.

А вообще лучше работать с docker-compose. Через консоль работать замучаешься, удобнее работать с Dockerfile и docker-compose.yml, он еще и укажет в логах работу контейнеров, с которыми работает.